# When I click on Button, net browser window is getting opened istead of tab in Playwright

Tags: playwright-typescript

I am running my Playwright Automation script with Razor Pay Payment app. after successful payment, New tab is opened and on that tab there is SUCCESS button. When I clicked on SUCCESS button using PLAYWRIGHT, new browser window is getting opened instead of tab. I want it to open in new Tab instead of Browser window.

```
const [successTab] = await Promise.all([await enachTab.waitForEvent('popup'),await razorPayframe.locator(Located.byExactText('Authenticate')).click()
```

```
]);await successTab.waitForLoadState();await successTab.locator(Located.byExactText('Success')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-clicking a link usually opens in a new tab:

```js
await successTab.locator(Located.byExactText('Success'))
    .click({ modifiers: ['Control'] });
```